# WordPress form trouble

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Some help needed here, I'm building a one page wordpress theme and I don't really know how to make the contact form submit without loading. Basically all my code is on index.php.

This is the form submission php code above the get_header(); It works just fine but I can't really make it submit without loading the page.

```
if(isset($_POST['user_submit'])) {

$parse_uri = explode( 'wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] );
require_once( $parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php' );

$name = esc_html($_POST['user_name']);
$email = esc_html($_POST['user_email']);
$comment = esc_html($_POST['user_message']);
$website = esc_html($_POST['user_url']);

$msg = esc_attr('Name: ', 'silver') . $name . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= esc_attr('E-mail: ', 'silver') . $email . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= esc_attr('Website: ', 'silver') . $website . PHP_EOL;
$msg .= esc_attr('Message: ', 'silver') . $comment;

$to = get_option( 'admin_email' );
$sitename = get_bloginfo('name');
$subject = '[' . $sitename . ']' . ' New Message';
$headers = 'From: ' . $name . ' <' . $email . '>' . PHP_EOL;
wp_mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);

}
```

This is the jQuery post I'm using for that:

```
$( "#contact_form" ).submit(function( event ) {

event.preventDefault();             
var $form     = $( this ),           
     name     = $form.find( "input[name='user_name']" ).val(),
     email    = $form.find( "input[name='user_email']" ).val(),       
     website  = $form.find( "input[name='user_url']" ).val(),         
     comment  = $form.find( "input[name='user_message']").val();    

$.post( templateDir + "/index.php", { website : website, comment : comment, name : name, email : email, submit : "yes" } ); 
});
```

This is the site http://silviuandrei.eu/themes/bornagain/

Comment: you have to this using ajax

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for the `user_submit` POST variable:

```
if(isset($_POST['user_submit']))
```

But sending a different variable via `$.post`

```
$.post( templateDir + "/index.php", { website : website, ..... submit : "yes" } );
```

Change it to `user_submit : "yes"`

Comment: Hey, thanks, now I get mails without the page being loaded, but there is no content ( name, website, email, comment are empty )

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing it at *functions.php* using the *init* action:

```
add_action('init','form_submits');
function form_submits() {
    if( isset($_REQUEST['user_submit']) ){
        require("process_post.php");
        exit;//prevents the default blog output
    }
}
```

Note that using *require* is just a suggestion to keep *functions.php* clean.